# Traps on Sudoku grids

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku

[image: sud]

Let's have a 9x9 Sudoku grid. Where the dots are shown above, you are allowed to put the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8. Each of these appears seven, seven, seven, and six times. It does not matter which number is repeated six times. All rules of Sudoku apply: no same number in any row, column or 3x3 square. Given these conditions, what is the maximum number of traps that you can create such that the Sudoku will be unsolvable? Every trap has to be on a different 3x3 square. The dots always stay in the same positions.

Below is an example of a trap (outlined in red) on a different grid.

[image: trap]

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a trap?

Comment: @athin Place the numbers in such a way as to not allow the Sudoku to be solved.

Comment: Should we only place even numbers or we can also place odd number? Then what do you mean by maximum number of traps given each trap has to be on different 3x3? Does it mean theoritically the maximum answer here is 9?

Comment: @athin As stated, place the even numbers where the dots are. One trap per 9X9 grid. Then you can use the same grid with the dots as shown to create another trap. Soon someone will answer and it will become clear to you.

Comment: Could you please define "trap" in this context? You haven't explained what exactly it means.

Comment: @Deusovi.Trap is a 3x3 square on the grid with even numbers which makes the sudoku unsolvable. Just place the 27 even numbers on grid where the dots are. You will recognize whether it is solvable or unsolvable. Use a Sudoku solver if you like.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer anything so far... could you give an example for a solution which is not maximum? (Or some illustration to define what is a valid solution etc.)

Comment: I have added an example of a trap on another grid to the question.

Comment: In you trap example, why is that particular 3x3 considered to be the one that makes the grid unsolvable? How can a grid contain more than one trap - given that one trap already makes it unsolvable, what does another supposed trap in the same grid do?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis; In every other block the missing even number can be placed.

Comment: @JMP Ok, that makes sense. That definition should be made explicit in the question.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase based on my understanding. So we have to put even numbers on the dots such that the 9x9 sudoku is unsolvable while also maximizing the number of traps. A trap is defined as a 3x3 square of that sudoku such that if we remove all even numbers in that 3x3 square, the 9x9 sudoku is actually solvable. Is that correct?

Comment: @athin that can't be the definition - if there were two traps in different rows and columns, removing just one of them wouldn't make it solvable.

Comment: @Steve well it can be a definition yet the maximum answer is then 3, no?

Comment: @athin if I've understood correctly from the bad description, one could conceive of a situation (not from this starting grid) where all 9 of the 3x3 squares were "traps" - each having 3 dots, and an arrangement of numbers placed such that there's no legal place to put the 4th even number. I think the idea is supposed to be that although on trivial inspection it looks like a sudoku (no sudoku rules directly broken), each "trap" square has no legal place for the remaining number(s). The squares with 4 dots cannot be trap squares so the maximum cannot be more than 7.

Comment: Actually, the comment by @JMP is insufficient in general to define what a trap is. That only covers the case where a 3x3 block has 3 given even numbers, and for which the givens on the rest of the board directly eliminate any possibility for the missing even number. What if the givens cause there to be a row that cannot contain a particular even number. Which of the three 3x3x3 blocks contains the trap? And what about other more indirect eliminations?

Comment: Why 7776 and not say 9873?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I'd guess that would be a "trap row" rather than a "trap 3x3 square"

Comment: @Steve Indeed, but the OP stated that "Every trap has to be on a different 3X3 square".

Comment: You still haven't made it clear what "trap" means; there seem to be multiple possible meanings of the word "trap" that are all consistent with what you've written. I'm guessing that by "trap," you mean a square where, for some digit N, the digit N cannot be placed in any cell in that square, because doing so would immediately conflict with one of the givens. Is my guess correct?

Comment: @ Τanner  Swett.  Trap is a square on the  grid which does not allow the missing even numbers on that square to be placed on that square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a number of blind alleys due to bugs in a program I made to do an exhaustive search, I found that, defining traps only as 3 x 3 squares which cannot fit all 4 even numbers,

> 3 traps are possible.

One such solution is:

> [image: 3 squares containing traps]
>  In the above, there is no place to put '4' in the bottom right square, no place to put '2' in the middle square, and no place to put '8' in the top square.
>  Other solutions having 3 traps by this definition are merely different permutations of the even numbers, so this is the only one found by my program, which avoids duplicates by fixing the even numbers on the middle row.

Although the problem description only described a "trap" as being a 3x3 square, my program also allowed consideration of row and column traps, counting these as separate to a 3x3 square trap. This resulted in

> the same example being measured as having 9 traps.

Specifically:

> in addition to the above 3 traps:
>  - row 3 cannot contain '8'
>  - row 4 cannot contain '2'
>  - row 8 cannot contain '4'
>  - column 4 cannot contain '2'
>  - column 5 cannot contain '8'
>  - column 8 cannot contain '4'
>  In this case, each of the "row" and "column" traps was directly related to one of the previously-mentioned 3x3 square traps.

I'm not certifying the program as bug-free, but it also attempted to find at least one valid sudoku solution each time it found a valid arrangement with no traps, and in most cases did so. In some cases, a valid arrangement was found with no solution but also no immediately-obvious traps. Example:

> [image: cannot be solved by program]
>  This replaces an earlier example (which @daw had verified was not solvable) but which was not valid due having 8 '8's. This one has a maximum of 7 of each number as specified.

I further classified the solutions by number of traps found, and the program found an example of an unsolvable soduku for each possible number of traps

> between 0 and 9. The 0 and 9 examples are shown above. Raw program output showing layouts from 0 to 9 can be found at https://pastebin.com/uSSrvDq0

More precisely, the exact condition my program was checking to determine whether a group of 9 cells (whether a row, column or square) constituted a "trap" was either:

1. for all cells within the range, a specific number is immediately impossible due to the direct influence of other cells whose number is known.
2. more than 5 cells can be immediately observed to only possibly contain an odd number.

In the initial runs of the program there were many screenfuls of output showing "Valid arrangement found", before checking for solutions and/or classifying them by numbers of traps, so it had initially seemed that I was picking one from a very large number of possible answers. When modifying to check for ONLY those valid arrangements having the maximum number of traps,

> the following was the entire output:
>
> ```
>  dot         dot     dot dot
>          dot                     dot
>  dot             dot             dot
>              dot         dot
>      dot dot             dot dot
>  dot             dot             dot
>          dot     dot dot
>          dot                 dot
>  dot         dot     dot         dot
>  Without loss of generality:
>  dot         dot     dot 248
>          268                     dot
>  dot             dot             dot
>              dot         2 4
>  odd  2   4  odd odd odd  6   8  odd
>  6 8             dot             2 4
>          268     dot dot
>          268                 246
>  dot         dot     dot         dot
>  Valid arrangement found:
>   2  odd odd  4  odd  6   8  odd odd
>  odd      8  odd odd odd     odd  6
>   6  odd odd odd  2  odd odd odd  4
>  odd     odd  8  odd odd  4  odd odd
>  odd  2   4  odd odd odd  6   8  odd
>   8  odd odd odd  6      odd odd  2
>  odd odd  2  odd  4   8  odd     odd
>  odd      6  odd odd odd odd  2  odd
>   4  odd odd  6  odd  2  odd odd  8
> ```

Comment: This last sudoku has no solution

Comment: If a trap is described as "this section cannot contain that number", wouldn't be all rows, all columns and all 3x3s counted as traps; because we cannot put any number to make the sudoku solvable in the first hand?

Comment: @athin more precisely, it's being interpreted as "none of the cells in that section can contain that number due to the immediate influence of cells in the same row/column/square that already have a number". Hence the possibility of a sudoku with no solution but also no "traps".

Comment: The dots are placed in a specific way not randomly.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis at one point (due to a bug in the program) I incorrectly thought that it was a much more elegant puzzle... that the maximum number of traps whilst conforming to the rules was zero, and that picking a permutation of odd numbers in any one row or column forced a unique solution. Then I found another bug and was a bit disappointed to find the solution was far from unique. However, I now see that there is only one answer with 3 traps once a permutation of the even numbers has been chosen... will update answer to mention that.

Comment: The puzzle asks about this specific Sudoku with the dots as shown. Do not generalize.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Isn't it okay if the post contains additional information beyond just an answer to the puzzle?